# Не могу понять, как сделать, что бы после команды !Бан, он больше не учитывал выданное значение в команде !Игра. Спасибо

Tags: python, discord.py

Не могу понять, как сделать, что бы после команды !Бан, он больше не учитывал выданное значение в команде !Игра. Спасибо
*Хочу, что бы после команды !Бан, бот больше не учитывал выпавшее значение в списке, и по команде !Игра, выдавал рандомное значение из списка, но без того, что выпало командой !Бан Или же, попробую так объяснить, нужно, что бы одна команда выбирала значение из списка, и удаляла его, но не полностью из списка, а что бы это значение не учитовалось в дальнейшей команде. А вторая выбирала значение из оставшегося списка и выводила сообщением

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
prefix = "!"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix)
a = [ '1','2','3' ]


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
print("The bot is ready!")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def Игра(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
await ctx.send(random.choice(a))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def Бан(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
await ctx.send(a.pop(random.randrange(len(a))))
```

Comment: Слегка не понятен вопрос. Перефразируйте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу, что бы после команды !Бан, бот больше не учитывал выпавшее значение в списке, и по команде !Игра, выдавал рандомное значение из списка, но без того, что выпало командой !Бан
Или же, попробую так объяснить, нужно, что бы одна команда выбирала значение из списка, и удаляла его, но не полностью из списка, а что бы это значение не учитовалось в дальнейшей команде. А вторая выбирала значение из оставшегося списка и выводила сообщением